# How to fix broken mp4 and retain all streams including gyrodata?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, mp4

I think I have tried just about all open source projects on github but I can not get anyone to do exactly what I want.

I have a SMO 4k which is based on Insta360 R camera that suffered batteryloss, ending in a broken video file. I have tools that can recover video, but not the third embedded stream which is the gyro data.

I'm guessing there is a way to make ffmpeg to "restream" the broken binary file, with the exact configuration from a healthy file recorded with the same camera ( BxH, profile, streams, meta info etc),and  retaining all streams, including the text stream containing gyrodata.

Is there anyone that have done something similar and got it to work ?